# Wordpress plugin development ajax url not working

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(e) {
jQuery('#m').click(function()
{
    //jQuery(this).fadeOut();
    var d='<?php echo $plugins;?>';
    jQuery.ajax({url:d,data:{q:10},type:GET,success: function(msg)
    {
        alert(msg);
    }
}
)
});
```

I have to develop my own plugin, basically Wordpress has an admin-ajax file which handles this type of request, so how can I make it request using its own file to handle an Ajax request?

Comment: Check if you get correct url by `alert(d);`

Comment: what is value of d variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for that you need to do it like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var data = {
        action: 'my_action',
        whatever: ajax_object.we_value      // We pass php values differently!
    };
    // We can also pass the url value separately from ajaxurl for front end AJAX implementations
    jQuery.post(ajax_object.ajax_url, data, function(response) {
        alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

and in your handler file :

```
add_action('wp_ajax_my_action', 'my_action_callback');

function my_action_callback() {
    global $wpdb; // this is how you get access to the database

    $whatever = intval( $_POST['whatever'] );

    $whatever += 10;

        echo $whatever;

    die(); // this is required to return a proper result
}
```

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'index.php' != $hook ) return;  // Only applies to dashboard panel

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));

// in javascript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
        array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => $email_nonce ) );
```

}
And Do not forget to enqueue your script :

```
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function my_enqueue($hook) {
    if( 'index.php' != $hook ) return;  // Only applies to dashboard panel

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', plugins_url( '/js/my_query.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'));

    // in javascript, object properties are accessed as ajax_object.ajax_url, ajax_object.we_value
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'we_value' => $email_nonce ) );
}
```